# Separating a five-character input (integer or string) with spaces

Tags: c, string, integer

I'm an idiot. I have a programming exercise where the user inputs a five-letter number and I have to separate the numbers by spaces. If the user inputted "54321", the output would have to be "5 4 3 2 1".

So far my solution has just been to take the input as five separate characters and repeat them with added spaces, à la:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char k1, k2, k3, k4, k5;

    printf("Input five numbers: ");
    scanf("%c%c%c%c%c", &k1, &k2, &k3, &k4, &k5);

    printf("%c %c %c %c %c", &k1, &k2, &k3, &k4, &k5);
    return 0;
}
```

This hasn't worked, and every time I run the program the output comes as the same five nonsense characters.

```
Input five numbers: 55555
▼ ▲ ↔ ∟ ←
```

Please keep in mind that I'm an idiot. Use idiot-friendly language, I'll recoup the cost of the finger paint/crayons you may have to use.

Comment: you're giving the adress of your k variable instead of the value in the printf. Remove the & in printf.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten how to print values using `printf`. Please refresh how to do it in your text-book. And about the difference between `scanf` and `printf`.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings, and at least try to fix all warnings before asking a question like this (e.g., `gcc` `-Wall`, possibly `-Werror`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%c %c %c %c %c", &k1, &k2, &k3, &k4, &k5);
```

Change to:

```
printf("%c %c %c %c %c", k1, k2, k3, k4, k5);  // Remove the & symbols.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you've done it well.. Only a  simple mistake has followed you to this error. When printing values don't use & sign unless you need to print the address of a variable. I just removed it and that's all. You've done it nicely!

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char k1, k2, k3, k4, k5;

```
printf("Input five numbers: ");
scanf("%c%c%c%c%c", &k1, &k2, &k3, &k4, &k5);

printf("%c %c %c %c %c", k1, k2, k3, k4, k5);
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No needs for crayons or simple language, you are passing the address of your variables to the printf instead of the variables itself.

```
printf("%c %c %c %c %c", k1, k2, k3, k4, k5);
```

Try this! Also, using five whole variables it's a bit of a memory waste. For the sake of learning, you could try to fetch the given characters one by one, using just one variable :P explore the C functions!